# JavaScript Sorted List, want to show text next to each item

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to display the name of the location next to the miles in the ordered list, how would I do that? (ie. - Atlantic City: 5 miles)

`var EggHarbor = getDistanceFromLatLonInM(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, 39.4216612, -74.5958953);
var AtlanticCity = getDistanceFromLatLonInM(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, 39.3491665, -74.5252633);
var CapeMay = getDistanceFromLatLonInM(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, 39.0281821, -74.9193117);
var Galloway = getDistanceFromLatLonInM(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, 39.4721364, -74.5155441);
    var AllLocations = [EggHarbor, AtlanticCity, CapeMay, Galloway];

    LLength = AllLocations.length;
    AllLocations.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; });
    text = "<ul>";
    for (i = 0; i < LLength; i++) {
        text += "<li>" + Math.trunc(AllLocations[i]) + " miles</li>";
    }
    text += "</ul>";
    
    document.getElementById("dis").innerHTML = text;`

  
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make each location into an object:

```
var EggHarbor = {
  name: "EggHarbor ", 
  distance: getDistanceFromLatLonInM(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, 39.4216612, -74.5958953)
};
```

Then when creating each list element:

```
text += "<li>" + AllLocations[i].name + ": " + Math.trunc(AllLocations[i].distance) + " miles</li>";
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!